# Serializing a Dictionary<> object with DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, json, silverlight, serialization

I have the following `Dictionary<>` object:

```
Dictionary<String, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parameters.Add("username", "mike");
parameters.Add("password", "secret");
parameters.Add("persist", false);
```

When I serialize it:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
   DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(parameters.GetType());
   serializer.WriteObject(stream, parameters);

   byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
   string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

   return json;
}
```

I get the following:

```
"[{\"Key\":\"username\",\"Value\":\"mike\"},{\"Key\":\"password\",\"Value\":\"secret\"},{\"Key\":\"persist\",\"Value\":false}]"
```

What I want to get is a raw key/value pair map, like so:

```
"{\"username\":\"mike\", \"password\":\"secret\", \"persist\": false}"
```

I've tried setting `UseSimpleDictionaryFormat` to true, but this property has no effect nor is its intended use documented anywhere I can find.

I can't use a custom class, since the parameter key/value pairs is not known at compile time.

I also cannot use a third party library, such as JSon.NET.  I'm using the Silverlight framework and the Windows Phone 8 runtime.

Comment: Mike `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);` does exactly what you want and according to this [page](http://json.codeplex.com/) it supports Silverlight,windows phone and winRT.

Comment: As I said, I cannot use third party libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try serializing this

```
var parameters = new
{
    username = "mike",
    password = "secret",
    persist = false
}
```

Comment: The DataContractJsonSerializer is basically broken. This approach sounds sane; if possible (I don't know about win8) use the JavascriptSerializer, which _only_ merit is that it is able to serialize dictionaries.

Comment: Agree faester about JavaScriptSerializer

Comment: @faester - Unfortunately, `JavaScriptSerializer` is not available in the Silverlight framework.

Comment: @karaxuna - This is a decent approach, however my class currently has an `AddParameter(string, object)` method to add parameters.  I could change the method to take all the parameters at once, however I don't believe you can pass an anonymous type into a method.

Comment: I actually ended up just writing proxy objects for all the various types of parameters, even though this'll be a ton more code, however I think this approach would probably be the best way to go if I really wanted to get this working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After adding System.Json as a reference, use this helper class to construct the JSON properties:

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static KeyValuePair<string, JsonValue> CreateProperty(string name, dynamic value)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<string, JsonValue>(name, new JsonPrimitive(value));
    }
}
```

The following LINQ query will dynamically return the JSON properties as a JsonArray using the Helper class.

```
var result = from item in parameters
             select new JsonObject(JsonHelper.CreateProperty(item.Key, item.Value));

string json = (new JsonArray(result)).ToString();
```

Result:

```
[{\"username\":\"mike\"},{\"password\":\"secret\"},{\"persist\":false}]
```